# file logging using serilog .net core project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

i am trying to use serilog for file logging on a .net core project, and I want to use a log file for events, and another log file for errors. Ill add the appsetting.json file:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "Contains(SourceContext, 'AspNetCoreSerilogDemo.TestLogApi') and (@Level = 'Error' or @Level = 'Fatal' or @Level = 'Warning')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/Error/applog_.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [Thread:{ThreadId}] [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "Contains(SourceContext, 'AspNetCoreSerilogDemo.TestLogApi') and (@Level = 'Information')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/Event/applog_.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId", "WithThreadName" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "AspNetCoreSerilogDemo"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, whether I add an information message (Log.Information()) or fatal message (Log.Fatal()), the message is added to the event log file and to the error log file, without distinguishing the type of message.
how can I fix it?
Thanks ahead.

Comment: What do you mean about 'without distinguish', they are randomly added to event log file and error log file?